# Spyder keyboard shortcut to change focus to Help pane

Tags: spyder

According to [this page](https://datarebellion.com/blog/getting-to-know-the-spyder-ide-for-python), `Ctrl + Shift + H` changes focus to the Help pane.

I tried it from both the console and editor panes.  If the Help pane is hidden (e.g., by the Variable Explorer pane), then the Help pane is brought to the front.

`Ctrl + Shift + H` does not, however, change focus to the Help pane.  The insertion point remains blinking in whatever window had the focus.  As well, pressing `Shift + Ctrl + Alt + M` maximizes whatever window had the focus.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for changing focus to the Help pane?